# zsh sometimes doesn't show stdout

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

When I have a command that generates a lot into stdout zsh recently (last 6 months AFAIR) stopped showing the output.

e.g.
when I do a:

```
for i in `seq 2000`; do echo AAA; done
```

I don't get any output, and even when I press new line (enter) the cursor doesn't move, but the requests are going out.

When I reduce the number in `seq`:

```
for i in `seq 20`; do echo AAA; done
```

I do get output.

When I run both commands in bash I get output in each case.
What happened to zsh? Did it start to buffer the stdout somehow? Or is it `seq` fault somehow?

zsh version: debian/5.6.2-3

My .zshrc is quite long, but it worked in one version and in another it started behaving so strangely. Is there an option for buffering or something?

UPDATE:
I've narrowed it down to following entry in my zshrc:

```
case $TERM in                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  *xterm*|rxvt|(dt|k|E|a)term)                                                  
    preexec () {                                                                
      print -Pn "\e]2;$1\a"                                                     
    }                                                                           
  ;;                                                                            
  screen*)                                                                      
    preexec () {                                                                
      print -Pn "\e\"$1\e\134"                                                  
    }                                                                           
  ;;                                                                            
esac
```

Comment: I have no problems with zsh 5.6.2; please include details about your version (`echo $ZSH_PATCHLEVEL`) and try without loading your personal config (`zsh -f`).

Comment: @mpy Thanks, I added my version and without my personal config it works. What can be causing such strange behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately, also with the code you posted (to change title of terminal / screen to currently running program), I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe. I even went up to 2000000 without problems.